# How to import jQuery as a global variable with Symfony's AssetMapper?

Tags: jquery, symfony, symfony-assetmapper

With `webpack-encore` a script file could be added error free to a template with `{{ encore_entry_script_tags('add-food') }}` inside a properly formed JavaScript block. What is not at all clear is how to achieve the same effect with AssetMapper. The closest I ever get is something like this in a browser's console:  `$ is not defined at add-food-81afe070e8be2f50bb5e13fa8d7573cf.js:1:1`.

I've tried a wild variety of options without success. What am I missing?

Current environment:

`../assets/vendor/installed.php`:

```php
// ...
  'jquery' => 
  array (
    'version' => '3.7.1',
    'dependencies' => 
//...
```

`../assets/app.js`:

```js
import './bootstrap.js';

import './styles/app.css'
import './styles/jquery-ui.min.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './add-food.js';

import jquery from 'jquery';
const $ = jquery;
window.$ = $;
```

`base.html.twig` includes:

```
{# ... #}
{% block javascripts %}
    {% block importmap %}{{ importmap('app') }}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
{# ... #}
```

Comment: Why are you importing `jquery` from `'jquery'`, and not `$`, as shown in [the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/asset_mapper.html#global-variables-like-jquery)? (And asides, why do you have an `importmap` block? That doesn't seem to make a lot of sense)

Comment: your problem here is not a global variable, you are trying to use `$` in `add-food`, which is imported **before** you create the global variable. In this case, instead of creating a global variable, what you need to do is to `import $ from 'jquery'` on each script that needs it. The file will still be only requested once.

Comment: Let me see if I understand. Are you saying that `import $ from 'jquery'` goes in, e.g., `add-food.js`? And then how exactly is `add-food.js` added to the template where it's needed?

Comment: `import $ from 'jquery'` goes on each file where you use jquery, and want to use `$`. In the code you show, you are importing `add-food` in `app.js`... so anywhere you do `importmap('app')`, your `add-food.js` would be available.

Comment: I get it! Another example of my making things substantially more complex than they need to be. I do wish that documentation is more explicit, but this is what happens when code writers also write the documentation. Now on the air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here, in the error shown in the question, is not necessarily about creating a global variable.

The error comes from `add-food.js`, which is imported **before** you create the global `$` variable in `app.js`.

You could try importing `add-food.js` after creating the global variable, but it looks like in this case, instead of creating a global variable, what you should to do is to `import $ from 'jquery'` on each script that needs it.

The file will still be only requested once, and you won't be creating an unnecessary global variable. (In any case, in your example the global variable should be created, although I'd probably do it like in the docs

Comment: I confess that I remain unclear on how to accomplish having a script in a template. One, I remove `add-food.js` from `app.js`. Then put `import $ from 'jquery'`at the top of  `add-food.js` and add the asset `add-food.js` in a javascript block, I still get `$ is not defined`. Can you point me to an example where a template calls a script unique to the template?

Comment: Actual error is `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Comment: I don't follow the "having a script in a template" thing. You mean a having page-specific scripts/styles? That's covered in the docs, look at the end. Going to sleep now, but if you can't make it work with the information on the docs, post a new question, hopefully clearing things up a bit about what you want to accomplish. Try to create a simple, minimal, reproducible example. It usually helps to understand the issue at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and knowledge. I've sorted things out & now have a working page-specific script. Next up, getting a modal form to work properly. Good thing there's symfonycasts to smooth the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with external packages where I cant put import. This solution works form me

create script `/assets/provide_jquery.js`

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

and in your main js file `/assets/app.js`
add provide on top of your imports

```
import './provide_jquery.js';
import './bootstrap.js';
```