Symfony asset Mapper and Jquery
I try to add Jquery into my web application using Symfony Assetmapper.
As descrived in the doc, i used the following command to add Jquery in the App.js and in the importmap.php :
php bin/console importmap:require jquery

Everything works fine, i get the Jquery folder in my assets and Jquery is reported in my importmap file.
When my application is launched, i get this error :
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).collapse is not a function

I respect as recommanded to " import $ from 'jquery'.
In my folder , the "importmap:require" only create a file : "jquery.index.js"
It seems than jquery file is incomplete or something is missing.
This is the content of the jquery.index.js file :
/**
 * Bundled by jsDelivr using Rollup v2.79.1 and Terser v5.19.2.
 * Original file: /npm/jquery@3.7.1/dist/jquery.js
 *
 * Do NOT use SRI with dynamically generated files! More information: https://www.jsdelivr.com/using-sri-with-dynamic-files
 */
var e,t="undefined"!=typeof globalThis?globalThis:"undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof global?global:"undefined"!=typeof self?self:{},n={exports:{}};
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v3.7.1
 * https://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright OpenJS Foundation and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2023-08-28T13:37Z
 */
e=n,function(t,n){e.exports=t.document?n(t,!0):function(e){if(!e.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return n(e)}}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:t,(function(e,t){var n=[],r=Object.getPrototypeOf,i=n.slice,o=n.flat?function(e){return n.flat.call(e)}:function(e){return n.concat.apply([],e)},a=n.push,s=n.........

Is there another way to install Jquery using Assetmapper ?
Thank you!
I already change the order of import in my app.js file :
import $ from 'jquery';
import '@popperjs/core';
import './bootstrap.js';
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * This file will be included onto the page via the importmap() Twig function,
 * which should already be in your base.html.twig.
 */
import './styles/app.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77705551/how-to-import-jquery-as-a-global-variable-with-symfonys-assetmapper please check this answer looks like similar problem
